# OCPP 2.0 How does the central system male a request to the charging station?

Tags: python, ocpp

The information I inquired is only that the charging station sends a request to the central system. In OCPP v2.0.1, How the central system makes a request to the charging station and how does the charging station respond?
[I am using the below mentioned type of code for this:]
(https://github.com/mobilityhouse/ocpp)

I want the central system to be able to make a request to the charging station and get a response from the charging station.